# Is it possible for GNU screen to enforce a unique session name?

Tags: gnu-screen

The default behavior of GNU screen is to prepend the process id to a session name to allow duplicate names to exist.

For example, the following will produce three sessions of the same name, unique only by the presence of the process identifier:

```
$ screen -Sd test -m bash
$ screen -Sd test -m bash
$ screen -Sd test -m bash

$ screen -ls

There are screens on:
        2077808.test    (Detached)
        2077832.test    (Detached)
        2077852.test    (Detached)
3 Sockets in /run/screen/S-user.
```

Is it possible for GNU screen to enforce a unique session name and disallow the default behavior of "duplicate session name with unique prefix"? Ideally, I would like my invocation of `screen` to fail when an existing session exists.

Grepping `screen -ls` prior to starting a screen has not provided satisfactory results, due to race conditions which this method allows.

Comment: Screen itself likely has no central controller that could enforce that, I think it only looks at the list of sockets in the directory. So it could face the same race conditions itself. You might need to add your own logic to make sure the session names are unique.

Comment: Sounds like a simple alias/shell function would do what you want. Personally I always use `screen -R $NAME` to avoid this being an issue in the first place.